# Banner in the foreground isn't a valid image

Tags: javascript, image, foreground

i have a problem with the banner in the foreground.

I have uploaded this:

http://s21.postimg.org/g25v2uno7/newslavorobanner.jpg

The Playstore says this: "You must correct the banner in the foreground. Is not a valid image." Can you help me?

We have done it in PNG, JPEG with size 1024 x 500

I don't know where is the problem! :(

Answer (score -1):

This link refers to an html page, not directly to the image.

The direct link to the images seems to be http://s21.postimg.org/g25v2uno7/newslavorobanner.jpg